# Reload IMAP-Message

Tags: c#, imap

I have created an IMAP-Server. Now I am searching a way to force the client (in my case an iPhone) to reload a message, because it has changed on the server-side. Does somebody know a way to do this?

Comment: Did you create it based on the IMAP RFC? If so, wouldn't it provide details in there? http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt

Comment: @KentBoogaart: RFC 2060 is obsolete. The latest version of IMAP4rev1 is defined in [RFC 3501](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a message is not allowed to change in IMAP; the only data item that may be changed for an existing message is the list of flags.

If you want to mimic a change in message body, you effectively have to tell your client that the original message was removed, and a new one created. You achieve the former by sending an [`EXPUNGE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.4.1) response with the message’s original sequence number, and the latter by sending an [`EXISTS`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.3.1) and/or [`RECENT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.3.2) response, after which the client would typically issue a `FETCH` command for the new message.

Answer (score 0):

The IMAP server can't force the IMAP client to do anything.

The closest thing to what you're looking for is [IMAP IDLE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177). With IMAP IDLE, the server can push certain notifications to the client (if the client asked to receive them). The client can then do whatever it wants when it gets those notifications.